# Swift code question - what this code actually do? (? : meaning in this code sample)

Tags: swift

I have below code in my XCode project and I'm not sure how to read it apart from the fact it's a function which does not return and which seems to be calling other functions from the viewModel (correct me if I'm wrong). But what conditions are there? What does '?' and ':' do here?

```
@objc
    func topLeftButtonTapped() {
        isRootNavigationViewController
            ? viewModel?.close()
            : viewModel?.previous()
        viewModel?.didAppear()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Ternary Conditional Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71), also called *ternary expression*, usually used as:

```
let myValue = condition ? valueIfConditionTrue : valueIfConditionFalse
```

Here the ternary expression is abused. Normally, the same would be expressed using an if-else statement:

```
if isRootNavigationViewController {
   viewModel?.close()
} else {
   viewModel?.previous()
}
```

Comment: if/else is so much easier to read! Thank you for an explanation - that makes sense now!

Comment: @MahmoudZinji Huh? You are wrong. You should never abuse ternary expression when you don't want to actually use an expression (e.g. in an assignment). The readability is the most important thing when writing code.